# Is there a way to replace a Javascript library link in a browser?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Here is my problem.

I need to connect to an external website on the web (not my website). Most of its dependencies are in the same domain (/assets/...). But they put 2 resources in a CDN (here, Cloudflare).

But I can't load from this CDN, due to firewall restrictions. However, the libraries (JQuery related) are not forbidden.

Is there a technical way to replace this link at runtime to reference a more accessible location for these libraries ?

Comment: Can't you have them as local copies and serve it from your server (like how you access the other libraries)?

Comment: The main reason you server them from a CDN is for caching. If your website is hosted within a firewall, you wouldn't get that benefit anyway. It's ok to serve it locally.  You could setup a proxy that redirects to a local jQuery if for done some reason you can't change the HTML

Comment: If you want to do it manually, you can open dev tools, set a breakpoint in a script that is executed very early, then manually change the url's of the script tags to another cdn (like cdnjs.com) and continue in debugger... haven't tried it though so I'm not sure it works. Just an idea

Comment: A little precision : this is not MY website, just a website with Javascript tabs  I need to browse.

Answer (score 0):

### Method #1

Assuming you have a local web server running on your machine, a possible hack might be to edit your hosts file so that the blocked domain(s) is(are) pointing to your localhost:

```
127.0.0.1  www.a-blocked-domain.com
127.0.0.1  a-blocked-domain.com
```

If you can't access them at all anyway, that shouldn't be too harmful.

(You may need some `mod_rewrite` directives so that you don't have to replicate the full paths used by the original hosts to serve those files.)

### Method #2

To elaborate on Simon's suggestion in the comments: if you can somehow take control just after the DOM has been loaded, here is some experimental (and barely tested) code that you can try to run in the console.

This may also work after the page has been fully loaded, but you'll probably have to launch manually some pieces of code that were supposed to be executed when `onDOMReady` or `onContentReady` are fired.

```
var scriptList = document.getElementsByTagName('script'),
    hostList = [
      { 'source': 'a-blocked-domain.com', 'target': 'the-appropriate-domain.com' }
    ];

Array.prototype.slice.call(scriptList).forEach(function(s) {
  var node, script, host = getHostname(s.src);

  if(node = hostList.find(function(h) {
    return h.source == host;
  })) {
    script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = s.src.replace(host, node.target);
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
  }
});

function getHostname(url) {
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = url;
  return a.hostname;
}
```

Comment: I should have made this precision : this is not MY website, just a website with Javascript tabs I need to browse.

Comment: @Zofren - Both methods are client-side. They are indeed based on the assumption that it was not your website.